# Python error when runs in chroot

Tags: python, runtime, chroot, jail

I try to run some Python programs in chroot and I get the following error

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
```

I used ldd to find the libraries on which the python runtime depends and copied the inside the jail. Could you please help me with that?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to grab files from /usr/lib/pyshared and /usr/lib/python{$version} and copy them into your chroot.

Paths may be slightly different, you can try an strace python to see what its trying to load up.

Comment: worked for me I copied:  
`/usr/lib/py*  
/usr/share/py*`  

and after that I copied the libraries I from   
`find /usr/lib/python{$version}/ -name '*.so' -exec ldd {} \; `

Answer (score 2):

That is because some libraries are not visible from the chroot environment.

Copy them or mount them using `mount --bind`.

Just to illustrate what I mean (of course you need not to copy all the libraries):

```
# cp -R /usr/lib /home/user/chroot/usr/lib
```

Or, using mount bind:

```
# mount --bind /usr/lib /home/user/chroot/usr/lib
```

Comment: Is there any way to know which of these libraries are used by Python? So as not to copy useless files

Comment: You can try to start with `ldd /usr/bin/python`. But there can be other libraries also. Try to check with `mount --bind` if it helps. `mount` doesn't copy files, only makes special mapping.