# How to import a Python library from a Chroot jail?

Tags: python, bash, sudo, cd, chroot

Let's say I'm trying to execute some code from a library in a directory, let's call it `/home/user/project`. In Bash it would go like this:

```
cd /home/user/project
python -c "from MyLib import DoSth; var = DoSth(); print(var)"
```

Now my exact situation is a little more complicated. My Python code (including all the installed libraries) lies in a chroot jail. I'm trying to execute the code from outside the jail. I tried the following:

```
cd /home/user/project
sudo -- chroot $CHROOT_DIR python3 -c "from MyLib import DoSth; var = DoSth(); print(var)"
```

This prints:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyLib'

This is because the current directory inside the jail is just `/` becuase the previous `cd` statement was not executed inside the jail. When I tried it like this:

```
sudo -- chroot $CHROOT_DIR cd /home/user/project; python3 -c "from MyLib import DoSth; var = DoSth(); print(var)"
```

I got this error instead:

> chroot: failed to run command ‘cd’: No such file or directory

Is there a way to use the library without having to change directories inside the jail? Or at least help me find a way to change directories inside the jail.

EDIT:

What I'm trying to do is the exact opposite of the [suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757602/python-error-when-runs-in-chroot). I'm trying to execute the code (which is entirely inside the jail) from outside the jail. The code runs perfectly inside the jail, but not from the outside. `/home/user/project` is a directory inside the jail.

Comment: “*Or at least help me find a way to change directories inside the jail.*” If this was possible, wouldn’t this defeat the purpose of the “jail” entirely?

Comment: You know what a jail *is*, right? When they lock a crook in jail, they don't hand the guy the key and tell him to be good. The *point* is you can't get out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error when runs in chroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757602/python-error-when-runs-in-chroot)

Comment: Did you try? sudo -- chroot $CHROOT_DIR /path_to_python_interpreter/python3 -c "from MyLib import DoSth; var = DoSth(); print(var)". If the module was not found you are pointing to the wrong
 place.

Comment: @razimbres Don't see how it could help, just tried it anyway with the same result. The problem is that `MyLib` is a Python script inside a directory in the jail. The default working directory in the chroot jail is `/`, that is the exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by running a script containing all the commands I need instead of running separate commands, since `cd` always fails to run on chroot (even though the directory is inside the jail). Here's the command:

```
sudo -- chroot $CHROOT_DIR /bin/bash /home/user/myscript
```

In myscript:

```
cd /home/user/project
python3 -c "from MyLib import DoSth; var = DoSth(); print(var)"
```